# Number guessing game:Compare numbers and position in Verilog

Tags: fpga, verilog

I'm designing the number guessing game,aka mastermind,`1A2B`,And I'm stuck.
I'm having problem with how to compare the 2 set of 4-digit numbers and output `? A ? B`.

`? A` : when the number's position and value is correct,increase A's value,like,

```
1234=1234 => 4A0B,1234=1235 => 3A0B ...etc.
```

`? B` : when the numbers value is correct but position is not correct,increase B's value,like

```
1234=4321 =>0A4B,1234=7843 => 0A2B, 1234=5321 =>0A3B...etc.
```

Initially I'm thinking to compare both of them by each digit,but then when I use if-else if-else statement to describe it,no matter how I code it,it'll only compare 1 digit,even though I wrote it to compare 2-digit at once...

My biggest question is,how to compare these 2 set of 4-digit numbers and judge its position and value,then output how many A's how many B's.

Codes based on my thoughts and only able to compare 1-digit at a time,even though,I tried code it to compare 2-digit at a time...ultimate goal is to compare 2-set of 4-digit.

`Disp_Save` is register for saved answer ;

`Segs_R` is register for input display 7seg on the right-hand side.

`Segs_L` is register for compared result displaying 7seg on the left-hand side,default displaying `0A0b`.

`Css` is Choosing States,in this case,`Css<=0;` is return to Keypad detecting state.

```
           if(Disp_Save[3:0]==Segs_R[3:0])
                begin
                    Segs_L<=16'h1A0b;
                    Segs_R<=16'h0;
                    Css<=0;
                end
            else if(Disp_Save[3:0]==Segs_R[7:4])
                begin
                    Segs_L<=16'h0A1b;
                    Segs_R<=16'h0;
                    Css<=0;
                end
            else if(Disp_Save[3:0]==Segs_R[11:8])
                begin
                    Segs_L<=16'h0A1b;
                    Segs_R<=16'h0;
                    Css<=0;
                end
            else if(Disp_Save[3:0]==Segs_R[15:12])
                begin
                    Segs_L<=16'h0A1b;
                    Segs_R<=16'h0;
                    Css<=0;
                end
            else if(Disp_Save[7:4]==Segs_R[7:4])
                begin
                    Segs_L<=16'h1A0b;
                    Segs_R<=16'h0;
                    Css<=0;
                end
            else if(Disp_Save[7:4]==Segs_R[3:0])
                begin
                    Segs_L<=16'h0A1b;
                    Segs_R<=16'h0;
                    Css<=0;
                end
            else if(Disp_Save[7:4]==Segs_R[11:8])
                begin
                    Segs_L<=16'h0A1b;
                    Segs_R<=16'h0;
                    Css<=0;
                end
            else if(Disp_Save[7:4]==Segs_R[15:12])
                begin
                    Segs_L<=16'h0A1b;
                    Segs_R<=16'h0;
                    Css<=0;
                end
            else if(Disp_Save[11:8]==Segs_R[11:8])
                begin
                    Segs_L<=16'h1A0b;
                    Segs_R<=16'h0;
                    Css<=0;
                end
            else if(Disp_Save[11:8]==Segs_R[3:0])
                begin
                    Segs_L<=16'h0A1b;
                    Segs_R<=16'h0;
                    Css<=0;
                end
            else if(Disp_Save[11:8]==Segs_R[7:4])
                begin
                    Segs_L<=16'h0A1b;
                    Segs_R<=16'h0;
                    Css<=0;
                end
            else if(Disp_Save[11:8]==Segs_R[15:12])
                begin
                    Segs_L<=16'h0A1b;
                    Segs_R<=16'h0;
                    Css<=0;
                end             
            else if(Disp_Save[15:12]==Segs_R[15:12])
                begin
                    Segs_L<=16'h1A0b;
                    Segs_R<=16'h0;
                    Css<=0;
                end
            else if(Disp_Save[15:12]==Segs_R[3:0])
                begin
                    Segs_L<=16'h0A1b;
                    Segs_R<=16'h0;
                    Css<=0;
                end
            else if(Disp_Save[15:12]==Segs_R[7:4])
                begin
                    Segs_L<=16'h0A1b;
                    Segs_R<=16'h0;
                    Css<=0;
                end
            else if(Disp_Save[15:12]==Segs_R[11:8])
                begin
                    Segs_L<=16'h0A1b;
                    Segs_R<=16'h0;
                    Css<=0;
                end

            else if(Disp_Save[3:0]==Segs_R[3:0] && Disp_Save[7:4]==Segs_R[7:4])
                begin
                    Segs_L<=16'h2A0b;
                    Segs_R<=16'h0;
                    Css<=0;
                end
            else if(Disp_Save[7:4]==Segs_R[3:0] && Disp_Save[3:0]==Segs_R[7:4])
                begin
                    Segs_L<=16'h0A2b;
                    Segs_R<=16'h0;
                    Css<=0;
                end
            else if(Disp_Save[3:0]==Segs_R[11:8] && Disp_Save[7:4]==Segs_R[15:12])
                begin
                    Segs_L<=16'h0A2b;
                    Segs_R<=16'h0;
                    Css<=0;
                end     

            else
                begin
                    Segs_L<=16'h0A0b;
                    Segs_R<=16'h0;
                    Css<=0;
                end
```

[image: Thoughts drawing/writing]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a full answer since it is homework. Basically, for each of the four input pairs, you will need an A output and a B output. They need to be four separate bits each. Then for the final output you need to add up the number of A's and the number of B's. I don't see any addition in your code yet, and it looks like all of the comparisons are changing a single result instead of four separate results.

A bit more detail trying to clear up some confusion. Here is some pseudo-code showing the basic structure:

```
// digit 0
if (input_0 == goal_0)
    A0 = 1
    B0 = 0
else
    A0 = 0
    if (input_0 == goal_1 or input_0 == goal_2 or input_0 == goal_3)
        B0 = 1
    else
        B0 = 0

// digit 1
if (input_1 == goal_1)
    A1 = 1
    B1 = 0
else
    A1 = 0
    if (input_1 == goal_0 or input_1 == goal_2 or input_1 == goal_3)
        B1 = 1
    else
        B1 = 0

// ...
// similarly for digits 2 and 3

// add up results
total_A = A0 + A1 + A2 + A3
total_B = B0 + B1 + B2 + B3
```

Comment: Well,yeah,it's from the summer VLSI design course...I'm considering use 4-bit comparator,but I don't understand why it needs to be added,won't it change comparing value?and so for 4-digit input,I'll need to separate each for 4 bits and A's output,B's output,lite `Segs_R[15:0] = Segs[3:0] , Segs[7:4],Segs[11:8],Segs[15:12]` and each of them have to have A's output and B's output??? I'm even more confused...

Comment: @EEccmyang - I've added some pseudocode showing the basic structure I have in mind.

Comment: Ok,thanks,I'll try to think toward to this direction.I've had similar concept but didn't think that it need to be added.